What is the right notion of regularity for models over non-Noetherian valuation rings?
This is a soft question. I would like to know an appropriate notion of regularity for models over not necessarily Noetherian valuation rings. If I understand correctly, the notion of a smooth morphism, and the notion of a regular scheme need finite presentation or a Noetherian base.
So how do, for example, arithmetic geometers deal with this situation?
If I have a variety $X$ that is defined over a base-field with a non-archimedian valuation, are there "enough" models of $X$ over the valuation ring that are finitely presented?
I know this is not a very precise question.
Many thanks for the answer!

Why is smooth not good? The notion of smooth does not need Noetherian base, in fact, by Raynaud—Gruson (I assume you’re talking about rank $1$ valuation rings), finite type and torsion free (equiv. flat) implies finite presentation. So for flat models, finite type and finite presentation is the same.

Many thanks Alex, this settles the question!
